# Unicode Hello World Page

Tags: asp-classic

Can someone show me a simple ASP script that produces a unicoded webpage? Maybe you could write Hello world in a variety of languages.

Also how can I convert floats to string so that I can produce "2.3" or "2,3" depending on the country the page is being directed to. Does ASP offer functionality for doing this?

Furthermore, how do you convert `"A B"` to `"A&nbsp;B"` etc.

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unicode:

There are two parts in creating a true Unicode (utf-8) page. First you will need to output the data as utf-8. To instruct the web server to use utf-8, put this line at the top of your asp-file.

```
 <%
response.codepage = 65001
response.charset = "utf-8" '//This information is intended for the browser.
%>
```

Secondly, you'll need to tell the browser which encoding you are using. Put this information the html head tag.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
```

Remember that hard-coded text (in an ASP-file) will be outputted "as is", therefore save the file as utf-8 on disk.

### Localization:

*Also how can I convert floats to string so that I can produce "2.3" or "2,3" depending on the country the page is being directed to. Does ASP offer functionality for doing this?*

Use LCID to change how dates, numbers, currency etc is formatted. [Read more here!](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_lcid.asp)

```
<%
Session.LCID = 1053 'Swedish dateformat (and number format)
%>
```

### HTML encoding:

*Furthermore, how do you convert "A B" to "A B" etc.*

This is very easy. Just use Server.HTMLEncode(string)

```
<%
Server.HTMLEncode("A B")   '//Will output A&nbsp;B
%>
```

### Example page:

```
<%
'//This page is encoded as utf-8
response.codepage = 65001  
response.charset = "utf-8"

'//We use the swedish locale so that dates and numbers display nicely
Session.LCID = 1053   '//Swedish 

%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
       <%
           Server.HTMLEncode("Hello world!")     '//English
           Server.HTMLEncode("Hej världen!")     '//Swedish
           Server.HTMLEncode("Γεια σου κόσμε!")  '//Greek
           Server.HTMLEncode("!سلام دنیا")        '//Persian
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```