# asp string compare (encoding i think)

Tags: asp-classic, encode

i'm sending a post request to my asp page,
i use the parameter that i get to read file this way:

```
station = request.form("station")
StationFolderPath = currentDir & "iPhoneListener\Locations\" & station
fs.FolderExists(StationFolderPath)
```

with english letters there is not problem.
but when i send hebrew letters its not find the folder.
i checked it with this

```
response.write(right(station,6))
```

and got: `#1497` maybe someone know how to encode this `&#1497` to normal letter.

thanks

Comment: Your code is susceptible to a malicious form submission from a trusted client. Someone could enter a value of `"../.../../Windows/ImportantFile.txt"` into the `station` form key.

Comment: Please amend your question with the actual value of `station`. We need to know this.

Comment: Try the suggestions [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9757600/447356), you might have better luck setting the codepage and charset to Hebrew instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML Decode function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6116611/edit) and change the first line in your code to station = HTMLDecode(request.form("station")).

```vbs
Function HTMLDecode(sText)
    Dim regEx
    Dim matches
    Dim match
    sText = Replace(sText, "&quot;", Chr(34))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&lt;"  , Chr(60))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&gt;"  , Chr(62))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , Chr(38))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&nbsp;", Chr(32))


    Set regEx= New RegExp

    With regEx
     .Pattern = "&#(\d+);" 'Match html unicode escapes
     .Global = True
    End With

    Set matches = regEx.Execute(sText)

    'Iterate over matches
    For Each match in matches
        'For each unicode match, replace the whole match, with the ChrW of the digits.

        sText = Replace(sText, match.Value, ChrW(match.SubMatches(0)))
    Next

    HTMLDecode = sText
End Function
```